# How to write a GUI editor for Graph or Tree structures

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`Unity3D`'s `Mecanim` animations system has a custom `EditorWindow` that allows to define a tree (a blend tree in this case) thorough GUI.

It looks like:

[image]

It offers the possibility of creating nodes (states) and connect them (transitions).

Now, I'm developing some graph and and tree structure and I would like to write an editor extension in order to allow my game designer to populate those structures.

I want pretty most recreate exactly an `EditorWindow` like the one of Mecanim animator (figure above).

My question is: are there any available components that I can use for such a task? Is there any builtin class used for the drawing and connecting boxes and arrow? Or I need to write completely the GUI elements by my own?

Comment: I don't know if this helps you much but by way of example, [here is a nice post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71979-Drawing-lines-in-the-editor) I use to do bezier lines in my editor windows.  It serves as a nice example.

Comment: @Jerdak thanks for the link too! I was watching this one out of interest since I'm wanting something pretty similar to the MechanimEditor for my state machines.

Comment: Well all i see are lines, arrows and textboxes.
So you have a collection of them, you need to write something that can create and store such a collection

Comment: @Jerdak: I found a simpler way to draw bezier lines in editor. If you surrond Handles.DrawBezier with Handles.BeginGUI/EndGUI you can draw into an editor window using unity functions. I'll post a snippet soon.

Comment: @Heisenbug o_O Very nice, I'd definitely love to see a snippet.

Comment: @Jerdak: here's your snippet. Sorry for being too late, but I had a very busy schedule last months...

Comment: @Heisenbug Nice, that's hella cleaner.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was not asking "for a find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource". I would like to know how reproduce a `Mecanim` like graph editor using `Unity3D` API or some available components provided by the engine itself (sorry if the question wasn't clear).

Here's my answer:

No, there's isn't an available component usable as is to draw that kind of graph, but it's quite easy to write your own. Here's a snippet with a simple example using draggable [GUI.Window](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.Window.html) to represent nodes and [Handles.DrawBezier](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Handles.DrawBezier.html) to draw the edges:

```
public class GraphEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    Rect windowRect = new Rect (100 + 100, 100, 100, 100);
    Rect windowRect2 = new Rect (100, 100, 100, 100);


    [MenuItem ("Window/Graph Editor Window")]
    static void Init () {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow (typeof (GraphEditorWindow));
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        Handles.BeginGUI();
        Handles.DrawBezier(windowRect.center, windowRect2.center, new Vector2(windowRect.xMax + 50f,windowRect.center.y), new Vector2(windowRect2.xMin - 50f,windowRect2.center.y),Color.red,null,5f);
        Handles.EndGUI();

        BeginWindows();
        windowRect = GUI.Window (0, windowRect, WindowFunction, "Box1");
        windowRect2 = GUI.Window (1, windowRect2, WindowFunction, "Box2");

        EndWindows();

    }
    void WindowFunction (int windowID) 
    {
        GUI.DragWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Have you got what you wanted? I'm also trying to get some simple state machine graph going on thus I'm interested in your finding if you could share them :)

Comment: @vexe: no I didn't finish to implement it. I'm working on several different project and this has the lowest priority unfortunately. If you want to collaborate to implement it let me know, we could eventually doing something together.

Comment: Spectacular! Amazing how so many tutorials out there are just pure crap. I've been digging for hours, reading 200+ lines long posts, and this simple 30 lines of code solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You are wrong dude. Everything you see in UnityEditor must have code somewhere. Your MecanimEditor is in namespace UnityEditor.Graphs.AnimationStateMachine.

Extend GraphGUI found in UnityEditor.Graphs. This class is responsible for drawing graph.

```
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.Graphs;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ws.winx.editor.components
{
 public class GraphGUIEx:GraphGUI{


 }

}
```

Create new EditorWindow.

```
public class GraphEditorWindow : EditorWindow
 { 
  static GraphEditorWindow graphEditorWindow;
  Graph stateMachineGraph;

  GraphGUIEx stateMachineGraphGUI;

  [MenuItem("Window/Example")]
  static void Do ()
  {
   graphEditorWindow = GetWindow<grapheditorwindow> ();
  }

....
```

Create Graph structure. It will contains nodes and edges between nodes.

```
stateMachineGraph = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Graph> ();
    stateMachineGraph.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;

                 //create new node
    Node node=ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Node>();
    node.title="mile2";
    node.position=new Rect(400,34,300,200);


    node.AddInputSlot("input");
    start=node.AddOutputSlot("output");
    node.AddProperty(new Property(typeof(System.Int32),"integer"));
    stateMachineGraph.AddNode(node);

//create new node
    Node node=ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Node>();
    node.title="mile";
    node.position=new Rect(0,0,300,200);

    Slot end=node.AddInputSlot("input");
    node.AddOutputSlot("output");
    node.AddProperty(new Property(typeof(System.Int32),"integer"));
    stateMachineGraph.AddNode(node);

//create edge
    stateMachineGraph.Connect(start,end);

graphGUI = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<GraphGUIEx>();
graphGUI.graph = graph;
```

Draw Graph.

```
void OnGUI ()
  {

   if (graphEditorWindow && stateMachineGraphGUI != null) {
    stateMachineGraphGUI.BeginGraphGUI (graphEditorWindow, new Rect (0, 0, graphEditorWindow.position.width, graphEditorWindow.position.height));
               stateMachineGraphGUI.OnGraphGUI ();


    stateMachineGraphGUI.EndGraphGUI ();

   }
  }
```

Override NodeGUI or EdgeGUI for more styling and drawing control.
Copy paste code from UnityEditor.Graphs.AnimationStateMachine.GraphGUI styling done in NodeGUI and EdgeGUI.

Comment: I'll check it . Graphs api weren't exposed at the time of this question was asked. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Impressive. Thank you !

Comment: The UnityEditor.Graphs.AnimationStateMachine namespace doesn't seem to exist (unity 5.4)

Answer (score 6):

This topic is quite complicated, but if you want a nice repository of starter scripts check out this forum thread on Unity's official site http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-node-editor.189230/

*Update: Someone has posted a complex tutorial series, heavily detailing how to create exactly what you've described. Enjoy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHTJmGGH92w.

Edit: I've written a fully functioning Unity graph editor in a GitHub repo. Primarily focused on skill trees. It isn't perfect, but demonstrates what a fully functioning graph editor could look like. Source code in the following link.

https://github.com/ashblue/unity-skill-tree-editor

Answer (score 0):

You could try making an Object for the data inside of each tree objects.
Then you could try using System.Drawing to create a custom control(square boxes in the picture), also use System.Drawing to create those arrows to each tree object. make sure each DataObject has ID's and information for where the arrows should be pointing.
If you need help on creating custom controls i have used [*this*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHhjhOr6zNE) tutorial on YouTube in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I find a Unity UI FlowChart Asset from Unity AssetStore, [UI Graph](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/ui-graph-51304) developed by Broken Machinery, and it is free to use!

Answer (score -3):

I've done an interface for creating custom graphs using a TreeViewer and checkboxers. Is based on an "adjacency list" idea. If you have the checkbox of the "root" vertex checked, it makes it adjacent to the other vertex, if you just want a few vertex to be adjacent, then you select each one separetaly. I've developed this for java, but I believe it could also work for your purpose. Here's an image that I hope that clarifies my idea.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PhT9.jpg